# All text is lost when using openGL renderer in batch mode

Tags: matlab, opengl, plot

When running MATLAB in a batch mode without a display (e.g. with the `$DISPLAY` UNIX environment variable unset, or with the `matlab -nodisplay` flag at startup), normally you cannot use the `opengl` renderer. Instead you must settle for the `painters` renderer. For example:

```
>> print -dpng -opengl fig.png
Warning: OpenGL mode can not be used in terminal emulation mode; ignoring option.
```

Unfortunately, `painters` often gives poor results when working with 3D scenes with patches, lighting, transparency, etc.. Here is one simple example (using a display for now) where the alpha is lost:

```
peaks
alpha(0.5)
print -dpng -opengl peaks_opengl.png
print -dpng -painters peaks_painters.png
```

[image]

---

Because of these limitations, I was very excited to find the mostly-undocumented `hardcopy()` built-in MATLAB function, which *does* somehow let you use the `opengl` renderer without a display. This function underlies the terrific [`export_fig()`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) function. Now I am able to very rapidly save high quality 3D figures in batch mode.

However, there is one catch: **All text is lost when the figure gets passed through the `hardcopy()` function.** For example:

```
plot(1,1)
title('TEST')
```

```
>> A = hardcopy(gcf, '-Dopengl', '-r300');
Warning: Failed to draw text string
> In /Applications/MATLAB_R2010b.app/toolbox/matlab/graphics/hardcopy.p>hardcopy at 21
```

The output figure is completely lacking any text (no axis ticks labels and no title):

```
export_fig axis.png -opengl
```

[image]

So what I'm wondering is: **How can I get the `opengl` renderer to work with text in batch mode?** Is there a way I can get text to work with the `hardcopy()` function? Perhaps a way to rasterize the text beforehand? Or a way to combine a `painters` hardcopy of the text and an `opengl` hardcopy of the plot? Alternatively, is there a completely different route to make this work than the `hardcopy()` function? Also note that the problem is unlikely to be with my system setup, since it is reproducible under both Mac OS and Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you read this [Mathworks post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/300393) about a missing text font?

Comment: @JuanMellado Thanks for searching. I did come across that thread before, but I don't believe the font is a problem here. I can use any of my fonts in `listfonts` and they export fine with painters in both interactive and batch modes, and with opengl in interactive mode. I can't be sure, but that other thread might have been confusing 2 separate issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Linux, you can use a software OpenGL renderer (modern versions of `Matlab` have one bundled).
Such an option does not exist for Mac OS, at least not with current `Matlab` versions.
Windows is easy - even the batch mode runs a display, so you can work as usual.

1. Run `Xvfb :1 &`, which creates a (virtual) framebuffer X server.
2. Prepare your code in some file, say `bla.m` :

   ```
   opengl software;
   peaks
   alpha(0.5);
   print -dpng -opengl peaks_opengl.png
   exit
   ```

   It's very important not to forget `opengl software`, as you imagine.
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   cat bla.m | matlab -display :1 -logfile log.txt
   ```

   which makes `Matlab` execute whatever's in `bla.m`, on the virtual display, and writes whatever `Matlab` outputs into `log.txt`. You can drop the logfile when everything seems to be working. Also, note that `:display :1` has to fit the number you provided in the `Xvfb` invocation.
4. Profit.

Comment: Beautiful! `Xvfb` fits my needs perfectly. I can't believe I haven't come across it before. Thanks.